# Zoomable image like google maps

Tags: image, web, maps

I would like to create a website that has a large image of a tree from a distance on.  When you zoom in it shows more defined image of the branches and then zooming in further the words will display in the braches. You can scroll the image to see all the other words. So its like google maps but for my own image.

I have tried looking for examples etc but can only find ones of maps. I believe I have to make different tiles for the different levels.

Is there any examples or tutorials out there that could help me or is there a specific name for what I should be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to use a tool called [MapTiler](http://www.maptiler.org/).

It's free, and you just follow a really simple wizard that just hides all the complexity from the process.

Anyway, I've posted a tutorial exactly on this topic which you can check [here](http://build-failed.blogspot.pt/2012/11/zoomable-image-with-leaflet.html).

Answer (score 0):

I created a Java based version of a Google Map Tiler tool here:

https://github.com/devldevelopment/googlemaptiler

This will help you cut up images as per Map Tiler but is free. An example with Javascript is provided on the github readme.

Thanks